# "Side-Pull" a mercurial repo into main project

Tags: mercurial

I have a repo in my VCS called `CodingStandards`.  In it is a `checkstyle.xml` file along with  `findbugs.xml` and it will no doubt grow in the future.

What I want to do is in my project `FunkyApp` is pull `CodingStandards` into the project and maintain the link to `CodingStandards` so that if I change it, I can pull & update in my `FunkyApp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all setup the CodingStandards repo in .hg/hgrc to make life easier

```
[paths]
default = https://url/FunkyApp
standards = https://url/CodingStandards
```

Then you can force pull into your repository

```
hg pull -f standards
```

This will create two heads in your repo that need to be merged with `hg merge` and then committed into your main repo.

To be clear `CodingStandards` will be unchanged.  `FunkyApp` will have all the files from `CodingStandards` imported in it.  Anyone else who clones `FunkyApp` will get the files without knowing about `CodingStandards`.

Answer (score 3):

[Subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) are what you are looking for.

However they forces you to have these files in a subdirectory of your project. There's no way to add juste one file to a repository from another.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and for introducing me to subrepositories.  In this case, they're not exactly what I wanted, but will be useful in the future.

Comment: If you are not looking for a "bidirectionnal" link, then your solution is better. But you can run in troubles if you update your two files in the `FunkyApp` repositories, the `pull & merge` process will be harder.